# Is it possible to revert to a previous collection of phone screenshots on the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have recently taken over an app from another company, we will be destroying the old build and uploading a new app with the same signing key, but I accidentally updated and published the screenshots for the new app (which looks completely different)

Is it possible to revert these changes on the play store or do I have to manually attain the screenshots and reupload them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option.

Play Store does not version app listing screenshots, so you have 2 options:

- Search online for a cached version of the previous app page to download the old screenshots
- Take new screenshots of the old app

both step will require to manually re-upload the screenshots again.

Comment: Any recommendations for obtaining a cached version of the site?

Comment: Try searching for `Wayback Machine` and `Google Cache` on Google. But to be realistic if the page wasn't visited a lot it's really hard to find it cached with images too. You have to be lucky :D

Comment: @WayneWhitehead please accept the answer if it helped you, it could help others :)

Comment: sorry, yes, I tried looking for the cached images but couldn't find any. Had to take screenshots of the currently existing answer, thank you for the help